# Mediaelement JS and JW player iphone portrait video showing sideways

Tags: video, jwplayer, mediaelement.js

Video recorded using iphone/ipad in portrait mode plays sideways in mediaelement js and jw players. Anyway to fix it in frontent without using ffmpeg CLI

Comment: This is an issue with videos filmed on portrait mode on smart devices. They need to be re-encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone videos shot in portrait mode are, indeed, a problem. You can fix it in Handbrake (http://handbrake.fr/) by choosing the default options, plus check **Web optimized**. Then go to the **Video** tab, and in the **Extra Options** box at the bottom, enter:

```
, --rotate=4
```

The leading comma is required. That will produce a 90° clockwise rotation. For a 90° counter-clockwise rotation, use:

```
, --rotate=7
```

For a 180° rotation,

```
, --rotate=3
```

Comment: Thanks is there any option in javascript to do this

Comment: No. Javascript can't completely reencode a video, on the fly. You must encode the video properly before calling it from your web page.

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest the css way?

```
  '-webkit-transform': rotate(+90deg),
  '-moz-transform': rotate(+90deg),
  '-o-transform': rotate(+90deg),
  '-ms-transform': rotate(+90deg),
  'transform':rotate(+90deg),
  '-webkit-transform-origin':'50% 50%',
```